# Sent offer letter to another employer

Tags: communication, job-offer, employer

Yesterday I received an offer from a company and signed and sent it back. The job does not start for another three weeks and I had an offer to work from home for a fraction of that salary.

So I figured I would do it for the three weeks and then quit because i have no other source of income at this moment.

Well I filled out all of my paperwork to this employer and had accidentally added the one from the other company. They of course caught it and told me. I then told them that it was an offer I decided not to accept.

I mean I can hardly tell them well I will go there in three weeks. Now I am terrified that they will contact that employer and tell them I sent them their offer letter.

I am not sure if I have any right or what I can do. I live in Florida (right to work state)

Comment: I suggest cleaning your question up a little bit, as it's pretty confusing to read. Create a few different paragraphs, for example, then maybe elaborate on how many companies are involved.

Comment: I edited this some, but right now it's not totally clear what your question is - are you asking what you can do to help minimize potential problems from the employer you wanted to temporarily work for communicating to the company you signed the offer for?

Comment: I am wondering if the employer i wanted to temporarily work for can call the job i really want and tell them what I did. I am terrified that the job i really want will be withdrawn because i accidentally sent the other company the offer letter

Comment: You shouldn't have even considered accepting a job which you inteded to quit immediately.  If it costs you both jobs, I'm afraid I'm not very sympathetic.

Comment: of course its not the most ethical thing to do. I am aware of that myself. The other job is barely minimum wage so they obviously don't care much about keeping anyone long-term. We are talking about a $10/per hour job and you use your own computer, internet, etc. and they are expecting you to have a college degree. Unfortunately my mortgage and bills have to be paid. i guess i am doing what i have to do not to land on the street.

Comment: I have been at home for almost a month already. not to go into my work background but i switched jobs and was promised a great job and after two months they closed the doors. So i am not eligible for unemployment. So i already used money to pay my bills for this months and when i start in three weeks i am also not going to be paid for another two weeks and then just for one week because it will be a week behind.

Answer (score 6):

Can they?  **yes**

Will they?  **probably not**

Doing so could potentially open them up to liability issues that aren't worth the hassle.

---

**However**, you have bigger problems.

Hiring on full time to a company for only 3 weeks is (your words, from the comments) *"not the most ethical thing to do"*.

When that company found you out, you told them *"it was an offer I decided not to accept."* when in fact you had already accepted it.

Your reaction to this situation is to panic (*"Now I am terrified ..."*) that the 2<sup>nd</sup> company may also discover your deception.

**Business is all about trust**.  You've given the first company reason not to trust you.  You are rightly concerned that the second company wouldn't trust you if they learned of this.

The second company might reason, "if she's willing to lie to them, she might lie to us".  That would ruin any trust they might place in you.

**The good news** is that as noted above, the 2<sup>nd</sup> company is unlikely to learn of this incident.

Comment: @Chad - I agree & thanks for the comment.  I've updated my answer.  I hope I've removed the opinion portion.

Answer (score 1):

You made a bad mistake, I won't go into the ethics, I wouldn't do it myself, but it's too late to undo. What you need to look at is damage control and there is very little you can do.

In this situation you have already given them an explanation. If I were you I would sit tight and let whatever happens happen. Any more on your part will just make it look worse. At this point it's just a dodgy looking mailing mistake.

Don't stop looking for a job either, this could go either way. You may be taken at face value on your excuse, or not. There is no way of telling.